# Accessing Azure SQL Stored Procedures in Azure Logic App Conditions

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I want to use the output of an Azure SQL Stored Procedure in an Azure Logic App against a conditional block. There seems to be no documentation on this so far or maybe I am using the wrong keywords to search?

I have an Azure SQL Stored Procedure that I execute and it returns the following output:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "x-ms-request-id": "xxx",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Date": "Fri, 15 Jul 2016 08:40:23 GMT",
        "Server": "Microsoft-IIS/8.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
        "X-AspNet-Version": "4.0.30319",
        "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET",
        "Content-Length": "78",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Expires": "-1"
    },
    "body": {
        "OutputParameters": {},
        "ReturnCode": 0,
        "ResultSets": {
            "Table1": [
                {
                    "Column1": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am interested in the Column1 value (in this case 0). How do I reference this value in a condition?

I have seen some people using Xpath (it seems like an early iteration of Azure Logic app) or some JSON-esque style of referencing nodes inside the results set but nothing seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the result set is an array, you want to decorate your action with a 'foreach' expression in order to enumerate all items, i.e.

`"foreach": "@body('storedProcedureActionName').ResultSets.Table1"`

You can now reference the value of Column1 field inside of the action inputs using `@item().Column1`

Comment: Hi Szymon Wylezol, thanks for the response. I guess the code above it meant to be done/added via the "Code View" right? I am just currently using the graphical designer to do all of it. I guess I can just use the "@body...". Thanks

Comment: Yes, you would need to edit your Logic App via 'code view'. The designer adds the foreach construct implicitly in many cases, but because the shape of the output of a stored procedure is not predictable, you would either need to just use @body, or edit the logic app json definition directly.

Comment: Hi Szymon, in the end I decided to through a different route but thank you for your help on this. I am sure I will need to know this stuff again in the future.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by 'storedProcedureActionName'?  FYI, the resultset is not actually an array anymore, although you may have hinted you can extract the array from JSON with item().column1, but that doesn't work either - item() is evaluated and comes up null.